# Using the indeterminate style for a progress bar in FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Is the indeterminate style supported by TProgressBar in FireMonkey? If so, how do you use the indeterminate style?

On Mac OS, and newer versions of Windows, there are two styles of progress bars. One is the determinate progress bar whereby you know the minimum, maximum, and current value. In this case, the progress bar is generally used to show the percentage completion of a particular task. Firemonkey supports this method by utilizing a TProgressBar's Min, Max, and Value properties.

The other style of progress bar is the indeterminate progress bar. The indeterminate style is used when the values are unable to be determined, but to indicate to the user that a task is in progress. It is generally represented by a progress bar with sliding diagonal lines going through it.

If it's not supported, do you have any suggestions for implementing this in a cross platform way, utilizing FireMonkey?

**Edit**

I know about TAniIndicator, but that's not appropriate in this case. I'm already showing the user a progress bar for a large task that is broken down into smaller tasks. The caption changes and shows the progress for each part of the task. Some of the sub tasks are indeterminate, so at those times, I'd like to just use the indeterminate style. I don't want to switch between a progress bar and a spinner. It would be too distracting.

This is a common implementation that I've seen in a lot of programs and is possible on each platform natively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make ProgressBar1.Value = TProgressBar1.Max you see a moving part in it.
I guess it is customizable in the Style Editor.

Not a progressbar but another component giving the user feedback: TAniIndicator

Comment: +1 I personally think TAniIndicator is a better component to signal "unknown amount of waiting time ahead".

Comment: Arjen, thank you for pointing this out. I hadn't even noticed it before because I can hardly see it moving. I've spend half a day trying to manipulate the style to get something suitable, but I cannot. I will put in a qc request that this feature be added.

Comment: I also try today to change the style, the StyleEditor is definitely not my favorite editor .....

Answer (score -2):

There is no moving animation when setting .value to .max in firemonkey, the bar just stays green.